# what is the generalization of this problem

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

$\text{Statement}$:

> In any partition of $X=(1,2,3,..9)$ into $2$ subsets, at least one of the sets contains an arithmetic progression of length $3$.

Can this problem be generalized?

> In any partition of $X=(1,2,3,..a)$ into $2$ subsets, at least one of the sets contains an arithmetic progression of length $b$.

In simpler words, what is the relation between $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Nobody really knows.  This is an open research area.  As Gowers 2001 says, “this has turned out to be a surprisingly difficult question”.

---

[Van der Waerden's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waerden%27s_theorem) states that for every $b$ there is a number $W(b;2)$ such that when $a\ge W(b;2)$ your property (“any partition … progression of length $b$”) holds, and provides an upper bound for $W(b;2)$.

However, no good upper bounds are known; the one given by van der Waerden's proof itself is ridiculously large.  (For the $b=3$ case, it gives the bound $W(3;2)\le 325$, where as you know the correct answer is $9$. The bounds obtained for $b>3$ are vastly sillier.)

I believe the current state of the art is $$\left(\frac{2^n}{2ne}\right)(1 + o(1))\le W(b;2) \le 2^{2^{2^{2^{2^{b+9}}}}} $$  (The lower bound due to Graham et al 1987 and the upper bound to Gowers 2001).  Wikipedia also says that the lower bound has been slightly improved by Z. Szabó.

A few specific values of $W()$ are known:

$$\begin{array}{cr}
b & W(b; 2) \\\hline
1 &  1 \\
2 &  3 \\
3 &  9 \\
4 &  35 \\
5 &  178 \\
6 &  1132
\end{array}$$

(Kouril and Paul 2008) No other exact values for $W(b;2)$ are known.

The [Wikipedia article on “Van der Waerden numbers”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waerden_number) provides more detail.

- Gowers, W.T. [“A new proof of Szemerédi's theorem”](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/papers.html) *Geom. Func. Anal.* **11** (2001) p.465–588.
- Graham, R.L., B.L. Rothschild, and J.H. Spencer, *Ramsey Theory*, Surveys in Combinatorics 1987, London Math. Soc. Lecture Notes **123** (1987), pp. 111–153.
- Kouril, M. and J. Paul [“The van der Waerden number $W(2,6)$ is $1132$”](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/TOPICS/vdw/1132.pdf) *Experimental Mathematics& **17** #1 (2008)
- Shelah, S. [“Primitive recursive bounds for van der Waerden numbers](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1988-01-03/S0894-0347-1988-0929498-X/S0894-0347-1988-0929498-X.pdf)” *JAMS* **1** #3 (July 1988)